# How to select an element with multiple classes in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
 $(this).find("tr[class='well answers-list radio-list array2']").filter(function(){
                            st+="inside array";


                    });
```

This code works fine and selects elements with multiple classes. But if I select it with 'well answers-list radio-list' omitting the last 'array2' class then it gives error. It's my requirement to omit the last class to be able to select other elements too. 
Is there a way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question is very vague and doesn't explain exactly what you are trying to do but you probably want something like:

```
 $(this).find("tr.well.answers-list.radio-list").filter(function(){
      if($(this).hasClass('array2')){
           st+="inside array";
      }else{
            st+="not array";
      } 
 });
```

Comment: I want to select 5 elements with one query. 3 of those elements have this as class ''well answers-list radio-list array2".While 2 of those have this as class "'well answers-list radio-list array1".

Comment: ok..selector without the last class will do that

Comment: The above code did not help :(

Comment: Nope, omitting the class is not working.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: And what does *"not working"* mean?

Comment: thanks, your code worked now.